# How to get google map link as a form in hook_form in drupal 7

Tags: google-maps, drupal, hook

I want to display a link, to google map, as a part of hook_form. This link should get generated based on the latitude and longitude passed. How do I do this in drupal 7? Please guide me as I am new to drupal..

Thanks

Comment: You need and embeed  Iframe o an external link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for a simple external link you can use

`http://www.google.com/maps/place/lat,lng`

eg

```
http://www.google.com/maps/place/49.46800006494457,17.11514008755796
```

for iframe

```
 <iframe src="http://www.google.com/maps/place/49.46800006494457,17.11514008755796" width="200" height="200"></iframe>
```